# dd taking weeks

Tags: dd, cloning

A few days ago, I got the message "[Windows detected a hard disk problem](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-DIRJ-OAf8hA/USDmXGC6ggI/AAAAAAAAB44/pSel_LDkIwA/s640/1.png)".

I got a new hard drive, and booted into Ubuntu using a live USB. I started cloning the failing disk using

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=/dev/sdc bs=4194304 conv=noerror,sync
```

That was on Saturday. Since then, 527GB have copied, or 73934 records 1859 of those records have been partial, all but about half a dozen in the last 24 hours.

At the rate it's going (1.45 MB/s), my 2TB hard drive will be done in another 12 days, on the 6th of October. However, the rate has been slowing down since Monday. 24 hours ago, it was due to fining in 10 day from then, on the 3rd of October.

Will the rate continue to slow down, or will it eventually reach the end of the bad sectors? Also, is there any way of speeding up the cloning?

Comment: `dd (disk dump)` is low level working of disk , so you can't want from dd to speed up.However if your bs == entire of your your if && count == 1 it help you to speed up.

Answer (score 1):

The slowdown is because of retries, you should be able to confirm that by looking in `/var/log/syslog` (or `/var/log/messages`).

`dd` is fine for cloning working partitions but can take a long time on partitions on faulty disks. In your case I would use [GNU `ddrescue`](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) to clone the drive, it spends less time on unrecoverable retries and homes in from front to back towards towards faulty areas when it finds them.

Assuming you save the log `ddrescue` can be restarted, when the cloning is interrupted, more easily than you can with `dd`.

Comment: He booted from a USB stick, it's likely those files are not being touched by the OS on /dev/sdb

Comment: @FazleA. Are you saying that a USB booted Ubuntu doesn't update `/var/log/syslog`? My experience is that it does.

Comment: If he booted from a Live USB, the Live OS will not touch /var/log/syslog of the OS installed on hard disk. The Live OS from  USB will create and mount separate mount points for its logs. That's what I meant.

Comment: @FazleA. You are referring to something that would be `/mnt/XYZ/var/log/syslog` not `/var/log/syslog` you're confusing things. To repeat: `dd` as run from the Ubuntu USB, does write to `/var/log/syslog`

Comment: My understanding is that the /var/log/syslog you are referring to does not reside on /dev/sdb and dd is not trying to copy that.

Comment: @FazleA. You misunderstand. The (USB booted) system writes additional output to that file with problems the hardware driver experiences while `dd` is running. I have never indicated that I was talking about a file being copied from the orginal (faulty) disc.

Answer (score 0):

**bs=4194304** is too low. You can try higher values, like **bs=128M**

You did not mention how is the new drive connected, is it through USB 2.0. If it is, then unfortunately you cannot get better speed.

Comment: USB 2.0 goes up to 480 Mbit/s, that is way over the 1.45 the OP indicated.

Comment: It is connected to my motherboard via SATA.